# How to unit test this coroutine without sleeping

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create function that would add following functionality to existing coroutine.

- Add cache to original coroutine based on arguments.
- Add ttl parameter
  that defaults to infinity, so that caller could specify how fresh the
  data should be before it's refreshed.
- If someone called cached coroutine with some arguments while original coroutine haven't returned result for the same argument than second coroutine should wait for this result and take results from cache.

I have a problem with testing that last condition.

```
def cached(cache, locks, f):
    @wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*args, ttl=float('inf')):
        value, updated_at = cache.get(args, (None, None))
        if value and updated_at >= time() - ttl:
            return value
        else:
            loading_sync = locks.setdefault(args, Sync())
            if loading_sync.flag:
                await loading_sync.condition.wait()
                return cache[args]
            else:
                with await loading_sync.condition:
                    loading_sync.flag = True
                    result = await f(*args)
                    cache[args] = result, time()
                    loading_sync.flag = False
                    loading_sync.condition.notify_all()
                    return result
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unit test such a scenario, you use futures, which you can resolve at will. Using a very simplified `@cached` decorator and function here:

```
@cached
async def test_mock(future):
    await asyncio.wait_for(future, None)

func1_future = asyncio.Future()
func1_coro = test_mock(func1_future)
func2_coro = test_mock(...)

func1_future.set_result(True)
await func1_coro
await func2_coro
```

---

Original answer, based on misunderstanding:

The logic is pretty simple: you have your cache somewhere, let's use a simple dictionary. When you first encounter particular arguments, you create a `Future` at the cache location. Whenever you access the cache, check if your value is a `Future` and if so, `await` it. Very simple illustration:

```
cache = dict()

async def memoizer(args):
    if args in cache:
        cached_value = cache[args]
        if isinstance(cached_value, asyncio.Future):
            cached_value = await asyncio.wait_for(cached_value, None)
        return cached_value
    else:
        future = asyncio.Future()
        cache[args] = future
        value = await compute_value(args)
        future.set_result(value)
        cache[args] = value
        return value
```

Comment: I don't want to use Futures explicitly, but even if I would that doesn't answers my question. How would you test it?

Comment: I thought I answered exactly that question...!? The scenario: you call that function once, it suspends to calculate the data. In the meantime, you call the function again with the same arguments. In this case, you do not want to calculate the data again, but detect that the same calculation is already going on, and wait for it. Are we on the same page here? Then my answer addresses exactly that: use a `Future` as "flag" that the calculation is currently under way and will be available soon.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that. How would you simulate two concurrent request with the same arguments without sleeping?

Comment: I think I like the idea of using Future here actually, but you haven't answered the question yet.

Comment: Your question is about how to *unit test* this kind of implementation, rather than *how to test whether the same coroutine is currently already running and will return data soon?*

Comment: @decee Yes, exactly